# Is Goedel's 1st theorem not algorithmically derivable?

Tags: proof-assistants, check-my-answer, incompleteness

First let me explain what I mean by algorithmically derivable.
An algorithm must be able to come up with the proof without prior knowledge of the proof, in the same way mathematicians and computer scientists are able to create new proofs without prior knowledge of the proofs.

Our proof deriver enumerates all possible axiomatic systems, and with each system enumerates all possible proofs.
It checks each proof to see if it proves Goedel's 1st theorem.
This algorithm will necessarily derive all finite proofs eventually.

Goedel's 1st theorem states no sufficiently powerful axiomatic system can be complete and consistent at the same time.
The deriver is complete, since it will eventually be able to prove all true statements and disprove all false statements.
This means the deriver is inconsistent, so it cannot know whether a set of axioms used to prove Goedel's 1st are consistent.

Therefore, an algorithmic deriver is unable to derive the proof for Goedel's 1st theorem.

Does this proof succeed in showing Goedel's 1st theorem is not algorithmically derivable?

Comment: Can you formulate a more specific question than "please review my thoughts"?

Comment: There is the little detail of having arithmetic around. Your recollection of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem is wrong.

Comment: Define "without prior knowledge of the proof".  Hint: I don't think that can be defined in any precise or rigorous way.  It's the kind of thing that sounds like it means something but is very difficult to formalize.

Comment: @D.W. it may be difficult to define "prior knowledge" in an all encompassing way.  Printing out the proof definitely counts.  However, the enumeration algorithm I outline does not possess any prior knowledge.

Comment: @D.W. Here is another way.  If there are multiple sets of proofs from consistent axioms, and we must choose between them, and our target proof only occurs in some, then picking the right set counts as prior knowledge, especially if the right sets are vanishingly small portion of the population.  From a Shannon information point of view, picking the right set is highly improbable, thus doing so consequently entails a large amount of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The deriver is complete, since it will eventually be able to prove all true statements and disprove all false statements. This means the deriver is inconsistent, so it cannot know whether a set of axioms used to prove Goedel's 1st are consistent.

To start with, your deriver is actually not an axiomatic system to which Goedel's theorem would apply.

But assuming I understood your description correctly, it'll simply "prove" all sentences for two different reasons: 1) for each sentence there is a system where it's an axiom and so provable; 2) systems it enumerates will include inconsistent systems in which every sentence is provable. So the deriver is trivially inconsistent and tells you nothing about Goedel's theorem.

Now, instead of your deriver consider one which enumerates all proofs in $PA$ until it finds a proof of Goedel's first theorem and then stops. This seems to satisfy your requirements ("seems" because you don't define "prior knowledge").

Comment: This seems good b/c Goedel would at least have to start with $PA$.  It is possible to prove the theorem with $PA$?

Comment: @yters yes, PA is more than enough to prove both incompleteness theorems.

Comment: @cody and the deriver can know when it has successfully proven the theorem, so it knows when to stop?

Comment: This answer also appears to contradict Boolo's short proof:  "There is no algorithm M whose output contains all true sentences of arithmetic and no false ones."  Since Goedel's 1st theorem is one of the true sentences of arithmetic. Alexey's deriver will have to start off with a priori information regarding the proof in order to guarantee finding it. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_sketch_for_G%C3%B6del%27s_first_incompleteness_theorem#Boolos.27s_short_proof

Comment: @yters again, we are only proposing an algorithm to list *some* true sentences, in particular the provable ones, in particular Gödel's theorem, which is provable, as you yourself mention.

Comment: @cody It cannot list all statements provable by $PA$, just a subset, I'm understanding you correctly?  So, to guarantee the algorithm outputs G1, it must be correctly selected a priori?

Comment: @yters No, it can list all statements provable by $PA$, which isn't the same as all true sentences of arithmetic. You really need to understand this distinction first in order to talk about this sensibly. All provable (in $PA$) sentences are true (in the standard model of arithmetics); not all true sentences are provable. If they were, then $PA$ would be complete and consistent and Gödel's theorem would be wrong!

Comment: @yters But Gödel's theorem, stated as a sentence of arithmetic, happens to be provable in $PA$ as well as true, which is why the deriver in the last paragraph works.

Comment: Thanks for your correspondence.  This is confusing to me, since the self referential sentence in Goedel's theorem is unprovable in $PA$.  How then can $PA$ prove the sentence is true but unprovable within $PA$?  Wouldn't that entail $PA$ prove the sentence is true?  This appears to be a contradiction, but as you point out I am not especially knowledgeable here.  If you can clear up my confusion I'll accept your answer.

Comment: "How then can $PA$ prove the sentence is true but unprovable within $PA$?" It can't! It just proves that the sentence is unprovable (and so is its negation). By Tarski's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), we can't even define "a sentence of arithmetic is true" in $PA$, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about $PA$ proving that some sentence is true.

Comment: But $PA$ _can_ prove something like "a sentence of arithmetic is provable in $ZFC$ but not in $PA$". Since we believe $ZFC$ is valid, this implies such a sentence is true, but on metalanguage level, not inside $PA$.

Comment: A good example is: $PA$ proves "$ZFC$ proves "$PA$ is consistent"", but it doesn't prove "$PA$ is consistent".

Comment: Thanks, this is sufficient clarification, so I've accepted your answer.  However, I would not say the thing that $PA$ is proving is equivalent to G1, since G1 both says the sentence is unprovable and it is true.  I'm not sure your point re: $ZFC$ & $PA$ fixes the issue, because G1 also says this problem applies to all sufficiently powerful proof systems, whereas your point only proves the problem applies to $PA$ and we humans supply the extra extrapolation.

Comment: @yters "since G1 both says the sentence is unprovable and it is true" No, it doesn't. You state it correctly in the question: "no sufficiently powerful axiomatic system can be complete and consistent at the same time", but definitions of completeness and consistency both talk only about provability, and don't mention truth.

Comment: @yters Wikipedia is quite good here, actually: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Truth_of_the_G.C3.B6del_sentence which explains why "The truth of the sentence $G_F$ may only be arrived at via a meta-analysis from outside the system."

Comment: @yters Also, Gödel's theorem applies to invalid theories (i.e. ones which prove (some) false arithmetical sentences) as well.

Comment: @yters Another possible point of confusion is that _some_ proofs of Gödel's theorem use the notion of truth (like Boolos' one). But there are other proofs which don't and it's those proofs which can be formalized in $PA$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65994/discussion-between-yters-and-alexey-romanov).

Answer (score 8):

Your reasoning is incorrect.

It is true that your hypothetical "proof deriver" cannot derive all true statements. No proof derivation system can, and indeed, it is not even possible to express the set of true statements in arithmetic, which is a consequence of [Tarski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) on truth, itself a consequence of Gödel's theorem.

However, your algorithm does enumerate all *provable* statements, including the incompleteness theorem itself.

In fact, here's a much simpler algorithm:

1. Print a [formal proof of the incompleteness theorem](http://r6.ca/Goedel/goedel1.html).
2. Halt.

So you need a much subtler argument to prove that computers can't do what humans can do in terms of proofs. Certainly you would need a better notion of what "prior knowledge" of a proof means. Indeed, many people today believe that there are no tasks which are fundamentally impossible for computers but possible for humans, and I know of no unassailable argument for that position.

Comment: Yes, the point is it proves all provable statements, and also disproves all provable statements, so it is inconsistent.  But, that is the only way to guarantee it will print Goedel's proof.  Otherwise, it must start with prior knowledge, as your algorithm does.  But, Goedel did not start with prior knowledge of his proof.  He had to derive it through careful thought.

Comment: @yters well if you enumerate all possible systems, then yes, you'll hit a few inconsistent ones by accident. In fact, Peano Arithmetic itself might be inconsistent! Neither humans nor computers can tell if a system (containing "enough arithmetic) is consistent, only if they are inconsistent (because they have found an inconsistency). Again, nothing the humans do is theoretically impossible for computers.

Comment: In fact you can imagine a program that enumerates all systems and all proofs in those systems, and then throws out all theorems from inconsistent systems as soon as it finds an inconsistency. One could argue that humans are running exactly that algorithm when they do mathematics...

Comment: If we assume mathematicians are reliably finding consistent axioms and proofs, then my argument shows algorithms cannot do the same.  On the other hand, if we assume algorithms can do everything humans can do, then we must also conclude we have no idea if our mathematical knowledge is consistent, it is a complete guess that it is.

Answer (score 2):

> Our proof deriver enumerates all possible axiomatic systems

But the set of possible axiomatic systems also include the inconsistent systems. On the other hand, the consistent axiomatic systems are not computationally enumerable, hence you cannot enumerate them.

But cody's point is probably even more relevant, since the algorithm can just write down an existing proof. That existing proof will be relative to some formal system like Coq's calculus of construction, but that should be OK.

Comment: All axiomatic systems are just finite strings of symbols, so they can be enumerated, along with invalid systems.  That's my point.

Comment: @yters The upvoted comment by cody about throwing "out all theorems from inconsistent systems as soon as it finds an inconsistency" seems more to the point to me. Or at least I get the point cody is making here, while I still don't understand your point. Maybe you should explicitly state your point and explain why you think it is important.

Comment: If you throw out all inconsistent theorems, then you still will not know if the remaining theorems are consistent.  So the boat you are in is no different than my boat.  We are in the same boat, my friend.

Comment: @yters And that is a valid point. So you have two different problems here: (1) you need to understand yourself what you try to explain, and (2) you need to find a way to explicitly state your points and explain them. For the topic above, both points are challenging. I am not even sure whether Goedel's 1st theorem does go slightly beyond the axiomatic method: "[but the conclusions of strict containment (or inequality) go beyond the axiomatic method](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43356/alternatives-to-axiomatic-method/43438#43438)" or not (after reading cody's answer).

Comment: That's a good point, it seems G1 must somehow go beyond axiomatic systems to apply to all sufficiently powerful axiomatic systems.